# Implement Facebook Like Button on JQuery Galleriffic page

Tags: jquery, facebook

I am using JQuery Gallerific photo album at our site.
http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/example-5.html

I want to implement the Facebook Like button and Open Graph Protocol on this page.

facebook like button

```
<fb:like href="http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/example-5.html" layout="button_count"></fb:like>
```

open graph protocol

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/example-5.html"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3261/2538183196_8baf9a8015_s.jpg"/>
```

I want to change the og:url and og:image links when user clicks on next button and previous buttons to the appropriate page links.

Let's say user clicks on 5th image, then the open graph protocol links should change to

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/example-5.html#5"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3150/2538167224_0a6075dd18_s.jpg" />
```

and like button needs to be changed to

```
<fb:like href="http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/example-5.html#5" layout="button_count"></fb:like>
```

Please let me know is it possible. A solution to this issue will save my life. Please help me with the code.

Thank You.

Comment: Are you using a server side language? If so, which one?

Comment: Hi Karim79,The page is html page. I am not planning to use any server side language for this page. Is it possible to solve this, using the jquery and javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same problem. The issue is that the social networking "plug-ins" (Facebook, Twitter, Google+, etc) all inject iframes in which they do their work. As such, changing the page's meta information happens too late, as it's been parsed to build the iframe and is both ignored after that, and inaccessible to any JS inside the iframe. I even tried deleting the div with the iframe and re-adding it after changing the meta information, but the second injection just never works as neatly as the first.

The solution I used was an old-fashioned link for the "like" or "tweet" or "plus-one" button that I'd update in the Galleriffic onSlideChange() method. After you encode the URL and title, change the href for the a (assuming it has the ID of "facebooksharer" in the example below):

```
$("facebooksharer").attr("href","http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u="+newUrl+"&t="+newTitle);
```

Of course, you lose the in-line count and "friends also like," but at least visitors can like the exact image in the gallery.